# How do I correctly use these CakePHP functions as Javascript strings

Tags: javascript, html, string, cakephp

```
for (i = 0; i < filesinput.files.length; i++){
        let row_i = document.createElement('tr');
        let row_i_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
        row_i_data_1.innerHTML = '<?php $this->Form->control("submittedfiles[' + i + '][description]", ['type'=>'text', 'value'=>$file['name'], 'label'=>'']); ?>'
        let row_i_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
        row_i_data_2.innerHTML = '<?php $this->Form->control("submittedfiles['+i+'][date]", ['type'=>'datepicker', 'default'=>Cake\I18n\Time::now(), 'label'=>'']); ?>';
        let row_i_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
        row_i_data_3.innerHTML = '<?php $this->Form->control("submittedfiles['+i+'][time]", ['label'=>'', 'type'=>'text', 'default' => date('H:i')]); ?>';
        
        row_i.appendChild(row_i_data_1);
        row_i.appendChild(row_i_data_2);
        row_i.appendChild(row_i_data_3);
        tbody.appendChild(row_i);
    }
```

I'm trying to generate a table with inputs when files are selected in the filesinput. The table generation works, but I'm having trouble with getting the strings to accept the php code. The code enclosed by `<?php ?>` gets converted to html forms when compiling, and JavaScript shouldn't have a problem with HTML as strings, so I don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: PHP code is executed on the server, but javascript in a web browser. If you want to manipulate HTML with javascript, then simply insert html code identical to the one generated by your cakephp form helper.

Comment: PHP changes its code into html before being sent to the client side though right? Also, the issue is with the datepicker which is insanely complicated, and it wouldn't really be feasible to recreate it in javascript..

Comment: Also, make echo  `<?php echo $this->Form->..`